# How to set FillEllipse color by user defined/choice at the development time in Custom Control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, custom-controls, system.drawing

Here you can see the control property of text and in the similar manner I want to do something like - `FillEllipse` should be able to decide the user that which color he wants to choose from the property bar (presents a right hand side).

For example - here it is given "pink" so whenever user drag and drops my custom control he will see pink color ellipse, but I want user can choose any color from the right hand side property window... as rectangle `BackColor` property.

```
public new string Text
{
    get
    {
        return base.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == base.Text)
            return;
        base.Text = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle rc = ClientRectangle;
    rc.Width -= 1;
    rc.Height -= 1;
    gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Parent.BackColor), ClientRectangle);

    gfx.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Blue, 4.0f), rc);
    gfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Pink), rc);
    //gfx.FillEllipse(true, rc);
    //gfx.FillEllipse(jj, rc);
    //gfx.FillEllipse(
    Font fnt = new Font("Vardhana", (float)rc.Height * 0.3f, FontStyle.Bold,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    gfx.DrawString(Text,fnt,new SolidBrush(Color.Blue),new RectangleF((float)rc.Left, (float)rc.Top, (float)rc.Width,(float)rc.Height),sf);                
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from creating an EllipseColor property?

Comment: Could u please show me the code to create EllipseColor property ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks "LarsTech" for providing the hint, finally i got the solution by myself but with your help. 
So as u suggested i added the property

```
public new Color EllipseColor
        {
            get
            { return base.BackColor; }
            set
            {
                if (value == base.BackColor)
                    return;
                base.BackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

And did some replacement in the code and it worked fine.

```
//    gfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Pink), rc);
      gfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(EllipseColor), rc);
```